# pytesseract for low resolution img

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Disc: I total newbie In OCR and looking for oportunity to convert image to text from image with low resolution [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvhpY.png)

I'm tried pytesseract with different conf, but it still fails convert image to text. As far I understand I need some kind of preprocessing before sending image to tesseract, I checked some options from related questions, but still failing in text recognition with pytesseract. Is it possible to do any preprocessing or tesseract tuning for successful text recognition? Any python code examples appreciated, thanks!

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
```

P.S. I have no option to increase quality of source image.

Comment: Please try to explain more what you have tried and see if you can find useful information in the documentation. Most of what you ask can be googled. If you have a concrete code example where what you want is not working, then you can ask for advice.

Answer (score 1):

I can use below code to recognize the image. I think the resolution is still reasonable.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("NvhpY.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

custom_config = '-l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 '
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config=custom_config)
print(data)
```

Result

```
Kpekep
```